# Could threads shares stack(like heap)?

Tags: operating-system

I'm not sure about whether threads could share their stack space with each other.

And I think this question could be spilled in following parts:

1. Why every thread has its own stack?
2. Could thread has no stack?
3. Or what will happen if threads share the same stack?

I'm confused with this question ... and I have searched some keywords but still no thought.

And I think stack and heap were managed by os, so maybe the reason why os choose to make thread stack private could explain this?

Comment: "I'm not sure about whether threads could share their stack space with each other" no.  Just no, by definition.  Each thread needs its own flow of execution and that means its own function arguments, local vars and return addresses.

Comment: 'Could thread has no stack?' - that would make interrupts imp....'very, very difficult'.  Without interrupts, management of CPU and I/O resources also umm..'very, very difficult':)